# Show new window from status menu

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nib, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New NSWindow from application - mission impossible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444453/new-nswindow-from-application-mission-impossible)

How on earth I can show new window - from my status menu application?
I have status menu application and method called

```
- (IBAction) itemClicked: (id)sender;
```

I want to open new window after click on status menu item.
I've created new window as a new xib file - named "Preferences.xib", with connection of window - to object window via controller.
New window must not be visible at launch - so I've unchecked option: Visible at launch, bcz I want to show it after I click item in status menu. I've created window controller:

```
@interface PrefWindowController : NSWindowController {
    // IBOutlet NSWindow * window; OKay this is removed, but still no result.
}
```

then implemented init:

```
- (id) init {
    self = [super initWithWindowNibName: @"Preferences"];
    return self;
}
```

and then I've created window in mainAppDeleage's init:

```
prefWindow = [[PrefWindowController alloc] init];
// but after that [prefWindow window] == nil WHY? :(
```

and in

```
- (IBAction) itemClicked:(id)sender {
    [[prefWindow window] makeKeyAndOrderFront:self]; // window will not show anyway bcz it's nil!                                         
}
```

Any suggestions please? I am desperated after 4 days of googling and unsuccesfull attempts :-(
Thanks. I am an objective-c newbie.

Comment: How do you setup system menu's item?

Comment: Eimantas: 1. create new cocoaclass - from NSObject, then add - (IBAction) itemClicked: (id)sender; and then add new Menu object to your nib/xib file. Then connect your Menu item with action from class.

Comment: i've forgotten: into your appdelegate's method: awakeFromNib put: statusItem = [[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength] retain];
    [statusItem setMenu:statusMenu]; to add your status menu to menubar. whereas into h file of your appdeleagte class put IBOutlet NSMenu * statusMenu and connect in nib/xib editor with your menu.

Comment: Remove the window instance variable from your PrefWindowController class. NSWindowController already defines a window outlet, and this is what is returned when you call [prefWindow window].

Comment: i've already did it, no result :-( there must be something else wrong yet.

Comment: problem solved: [check the solution here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444453/new-nswindow-from-application-mission-impossible)

Comment: This should probably be a comment on the question rather than an actual answer. It also seems like the referenced question is a duplicate of this one, also posted by you. Perhaps they should be merged together.